# How can i call C# from Cpython by mono?

Tags: c#, python, linux, mono

That's the background. There's a C-S framework. The client was coded by C# and the server was coded by Cpython. Some function was coded in the client. The server also need it to check to keep the client no cheating.

That's the question. How calling C# from Cpython in linux?

I google it and i find mono. But i have no idea about it. Does it real work?

Maybe you will say the socket can solve my problem. But i think it is expensive to change the framework.If it could, i'd rather to call C# from Cpython directly.

At last, I' sorry for my poor English if it disgust you.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is an open source implementation of CLR. Yes, clearly, it works: see the [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) site.

With Mono, you can use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net), the implementation of Python on top of .NET, to call C# libraries.

If you really have to use CPython, an alternative is [python.net](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet). I played with it years ago, but it seems in need of some love, though :-)

Comment: It is sad to hear a boy without love. And i am not sure he can work with twisted...

Comment: Twisted is the framework which the server uses. IronPython doesn't support it, too.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question: what you want to do is a CPython client calling a C# server, instead of a CPython program calling a C# library ? If so, then what's the protocol used between the client and the server ?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The language of the client is C# and the server is Cpython. The protocol between them is protobuf. What i want, for example, the client has a fuction 'add(int a, int b)', it sends the result '3' and the parameter '1', '2' to the server. The server runs the same function 'add' and check the result whether is '3'. The function 'add' was coded in the client. It is convenience if the server could call C# dll. I hope i describe the problem clearly this time. In our country, the teacher's day is coming. I strongly feel the miss by my English Teacher...